# Connecting 2 sections of a guest network using a pair of layer 3 switches

Tags: networking, routing

I have 2 subnets, these are physical sites which are connected with a point-to-point fibre link, 10.0.0.0/16 is our main site with our main gateway, 10.2.0.0/16 is the second site which sends all internet traffic towards the main site.

I have a requirement to set up a guest network at both sites, the guest network is on a separate subnet and shouldn't be able to communicate with the main subnet.

When I took over administering the network from my predecessor no VLANs were setup, and so far I haven't started using VLANs and I have been trying to achieve this without using them. If I have to use them, that's fine, I can set them up if needed.

In terms of topology, here is a basic diagram showing how the networks are connected:

```
Untangle             Layer 3 (FSM7326P)                  Layer 3 (GSM7328FS)           Network

10.0.0.1 (gateway)
    |
10.0.0.0/16 ------------ 10.0.100.200                       10.2.100.200 -------------- 10.2.0.0/16
                             |                                   |
                         192.168.30.1 --------Fibre-------- 192.168.30.2    
                             |                                   |
10.10.100.0/24 (A) ----- 10.10.100.3                        10.10.100.2 ------------- 10.10.100.0/24 (B)
     |
10.10.100.1 (guest - gateway)
```

Currently the routing tables are configured on the layer 3 switch for each site to handle the traffic between 10.0.0.0/16 and 10.2.0.0/16, and that works fine:

```
Routing Table for FSM7326P
Network Address      Subnet Mask       Protocol     Next Hop IP Address
0.0.0.0              0.0.0.0           Default      10.0.0.1
10.0.0.0             255.255.0.0       Local        10.0.100.200
10.2.0.0             255.255.0.0       Static       192.168.30.2
10.10.100.0          255.255.255.0     Local        10.10.100.3
10.10.100.0          255.255.255.0     Static       192.168.30.2
192.168.30.0         255.255.255.0     Local        192.168.30.1 

Routing Table for GSM7328FS
Network Address      Subnet Mask       Protocol   Next Hop IP Address
0.0.0.0              0.0.0.0           Default    192.168.30.1      
10.0.0.0             255.255.0.0       Static     192.168.30.1      
10.10.100.0          255.255.255.0     Static     192.168.30.1  
10.2.0.0             255.255.0.0       Local      10.2.100.200 
10.10.100.0          255.255.255.0     Local      10.10.100.2 
192.168.30.0         255.255.255.0     Local      192.168.30.2
```

Both gateways in this situation are configured on an Untangle appliance, with firewall rules configured to block any traffic between the networks, DHCP is configured on the guest network on the Untangle server, this works fine for clients connecting to network A.

If you connect to Guest network A at the moment, you can ping both 10.10.100.3 and 10.10.100.1, if I try to ping anything on the B side of the network I get no response. From the B side of the network, I can ping local addresses, but can't see anything on the A side of the network. I know that the routes I have configured aren't working, however, I am wondering whether what I am trying to achieve is even possible, or whether I am missing something.

**Can anyone advise how I can reconfigure the network to allow A and B to talk to each other, without allowing any communication with 10.0.0.0/16 or 10.2.0.0/16?** I am quite happy to reconfigure the routing tables or network ranges for the guest network, but some tasks I can only perform during planned maintenance periods (i.e. anything that will require a reboot of the layer 3 switches).

Comment: I think you already know this, but VLANs are your solution for this, and likely many other problems. It's no good kicking the can any further down the road, might as well get started now.

Comment: Thanks for the input, while I understand the basics of how VLANs work, I don't understand how they could be used to get this example situation working. Any chance you could elaborate on that please?